# Closed form of $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}x\cot\left(x\right)\cos\left(x\right)\log\left(\sin\left(x\right)\right)dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, closed-form

I would like to know if there exists a closed form for this integral

$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}x\cot\left(x\right)\cos\left(x\right)\log\left(\sin\left(x\right)\right)dx.$$

I tried the relation

$$\log\left(\sin\left(x\right)\right)=-\log\left(2\right)-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos\left(2nx\right)}{n}$$

but it seems useless.

Comment: You asked to compute the Fourier cosine series of $x\cot x\cos x$ in your other question (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1168081/closed-form-for-int-01-2-fracx-cos-leftx-pi-right2-cos-left2-pi-kx), so it is just a matter of exploiting the orthogonality formulas.

Comment: However, direct computation through differentiation under the integral sign is *way* easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There exist a closed-form for the integral. It is

$$\frac{\pi^3}{32}+\frac{\pi}{8}\ln^2 2 - 2G-4\,\Im\left[\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{1+i}2\right)\right]+2,$$

where $G$ is [Catalan's contant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant), and $\operatorname{Li}_3$ is the [trilogarithm function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).

Using [Cleo's result](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/920995/153012) you can express it in term of a [hypergeometric function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function), but finding a closed-form of $\Im\left[\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{1+i}2\right)\right]$ is a [well-known](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/918680/153012) open problem on [math.se](https://math.stackexchange.com/).